# How to add my application to my fan page?

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-page

Since [Facebook removed Application pages](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/), how to add application (newly created) to fan page? I've found "Create Facebook Page" in application settings but the link "Add to my Page" is missing!

Comment: -1   The answer to your question is in the link you posted - you should really read what information is in a URL before you post it.

Comment: Yes sorry about that, but I was searching for simple admin solution, one that doesn't require code tweaking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe this is not the best answer, but it should help you.

Go to this URL after replacing APPLICATION_ID with your application ID:

```
http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=APPLICATION_ID&pages=1
```

Answer (score 4):

Currently it is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
```

where:

app_id: Your app's unique identifier. Required.
redirect_uri:  The URL to redirect to after a person clicks a button on the dialog. Required when using URL redirection.

from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Answer (score -2):

1. Make sure your page is classified as a brand > App
2. Your App has to have the same name of your fan page in the name of the page I.E. bobburgerbar page should have the name bobburgerbar Burger App or whatever in it as long as it has bobburgerbar
3. go to app details
4. Under contact info it has APP your page should appear

And voila! your app is added

Stupid Facebook